# How to use Mercurial Pager extension in Cygwin with non-Cygwin Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, cygwin

I try to use from a Cygwin terminal (or XTerm on Windows too) the Mercurial Pager extension.
When using the Mercurial provided by Cygwin (v2.7) it works fine.
However, when I use Mercurial installed manually (v3.2) using the official installer the output either ends up directly in the terminal or no output is shown.

I tried alternatively the following settings for pager in my '.hgrc' (which is read), none of which work:

```
[pager]
pager = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\gvim"
pager = "C:\cygwin64\bin\less.exe" -FSRX
pager = LESS='FRX' less -d
pager = less --quit-if-one-screen -R`
```